# non-ascii fields in list of all members in launchpad team using the launchpadapi?

Tags: launchpad-api

I've written this python script to list all the display_name's from a team members in Launchpad:

```
from launchpadlib.launchpad import Launchpad
cachedir = "/home/username/.launchpadlib/cache/"
launchpad = Launchpad.login_anonymously('just testing', 'production', cachedir)
team = launchpad.people['']
len(team.members)
for person in team.members:
   print person.display_name

exit()
```

But when I execute the script piping it into an output file, it fails when finding a non-ascii name:

```
    $ python get_list.py > /tmp/file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_list.py", line 7, in <module>
    print person.display_name
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
  print person.display_name.encode('utf-8')
```

to tell Python what character encoding to use for unicode strings.